# React.js unwantingly reusing data-reactid when rendering subclasses

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have have a `Questionnaire` object that renders several `QuestionnaireOption` subclasses.  New `QuestionnaireOption` subclasses are rendered when the state changes in the parent `Questionnaire` object.

The `QuestionnaireOption` class maintains state if its "selected" or not.

**The Issue:** When I change the state in the parent class in order to render new "Option" nodes, the new nodes are assigned the same `data-reactid`, I expect the Option node to reset its internal state but it isn't assigned a new id and it has contains the wrong state (in this instance, `selected` is still set to true on a new object despite props being set with new data).

What can I do to work around this issue?

Here's the relevant code:

```
QuestionnaireOption = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {selected: false}
    },
    handleClick: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({selected: !this.state.selected});
    },
    render: function() {
        var fullClassName = "questionnaireOption " + (this.state.selected? "selected": "unselected");
        return (
            <div className='questionnaireOptionWrapper large-4 small-4 columns'>
                <div className={fullClassName} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    <div>{this.props.name}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

Questionnaire = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {currentStage: 0}
    },
    saveOptionState: function() {
        // dump option state into amber.js or localstorage
    },
    advanceWizard: function() {
        this.saveOptionState();
        this.setState({currentStage: this.state.currentStage + 1});
    },
    rewindWizard: function() {
        this.saveOptionState();
        this.setState({currentStage: this.state.currentStage - 1});
    },
    seeResults: function() {
        console.log(globalOptionState);
    },
    render: function() {
        var currentWizardQuestion = wizardQuestions[this.state.currentStage];
        var currentOptionNodes = currentWizardQuestion.options.map(function(option) {
            node = (
                <QuestionnaireOption
                    name={option.name}
                    value={option.value}
                />
            );
            return node;
        });

        return (
            <div className="questionnaire row">
                <div className="questionnaire-question large-8 small-12 columns">
                    <div className="questionnaire-question-text">
                        {currentWizardQuestion.text}
                    </div>
                    <div className="questionnaire-question-subtext">
                        {currentWizardQuestion.subtext}
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                        {currentOptionNodes}
                    </div>

                    <input type="button" value="Back" onClick={this.rewindWizard}
                        style={this.state.currentStage == 0? {display: "none"}: {}
                    } />

                    <input type="button" value="Next" onClick={this.advanceWizard}
                        style={this.state.currentStage == wizardQuestions.length - 1?
                            {display: "none"}: {}
                    } />

                    <input type="button" value="Finish" onClick={this.seeResults}
                        style={this.state.currentStage < wizardQuestions.length - 1?
                            {display: "none"}: {}
                    } />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your console you have this warning:

> Each child in an array should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of App. See [fb.me/react-warning-keys](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children) for more information.

<sup>If you don't, you're not using the development build: you should fix that.</sup>

React uses two things to determine if something is 'the same' between renders: the component class (e.g. QuestionnaireOption), and the key prop.

If either doesn't match the previous render, react considers it different, and the instance is recreated<sup>*</sup> and the subtree dom is discarded.

Assuming `option.name` can be used to determine equality, change your code to this:

```
    var currentOptionNodes = currentWizardQuestion.options.map(function(option) {
        var node = (
            <QuestionnaireOption
                name={option.name}
                value={option.value}
                key={option.name}
            />
        );
        return node;
    });
```

---

For reference, reactid is an implementation detail, and may change or be removed at any time.

<sup>* if you just change the order of items, it'll try to just change the order for performance.  There's currently a few cases where this doesn't happen, so it shouldn't be relied on.</sup>